# python lru_cache explicit modification

Tags: python

Let's say i have the following function:

```
@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def very_expensive_function(arg):
    ...
```

And during the ***runtime***, I can calculate the result of the very_expensive_function (without calling it) for certain arguments.
Is it possible to inject those results to the cache without having the very_expensive_function figuring them out by itself?

Comment: "I can calculate the result of the very_expensive_function (without calling it) for certain arguments" why not just put this faster method of computation inside `very_expensive_function`?

Comment: essentially, the calculation of results of the very_expensive_function comes from the execution of an even more expensive function, which among other things, indirectly calculates and some of the results of very_expensive_function.

Comment: Put the `@lru_cache` inside the inner function that actually does the computation. Consider splitting your code into separate functions if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `functools.lru_cache` provides no outside access to the cache. You should use a different caching object, such as [`cachetools.LRUCache`](https://github.com/tkem/cachetools), or wrap `functools.lru_cache` in your own object that handles the special cases.

Comment: @gjp, the one I linked, yes.

Comment: It would be helpful if you were to demonstrate how one can do this using `cachetools`.

Answer (score 3):

[ring](https://pypi.org/project/ring/) also provides modification features.

```py
import ring

@ring.lru()
def very_expensive_function(arg):
    pass

v = very_expensive_function(1)
very_expensive_function.delete(1)  # delete cache for 1

# other functions 
v = very_expensive_function.execute(1)  # run without any cache function
v = very_expensive_function.get(1)  # get only if cache exists
v = very_expensive_function.update(1)  # force to update
very_expensive_function.set(x, 1) # override cache value without running
```

See more for [feature document](https://ring-cache.readthedocs.io/en/stable/control.html)